# proof that a recurrence $j = (5*j + 1)\,mod\,2^k$ covers all numbers in range $[0, 2^k)$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

While reading [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/10fbcd6c5dc25bfe14e02fd93ef93498a393860c/Objects/dictobject.c#L289) I found that a recurrence $j = (5*j + 1)\,mod\,2^k$ generates $j$ recurrently in range $[0, 2^k)$ starting from any non-negative $j$ and positive $k$.

I've not found any sources with a proof of this statement. Could anybody provide the proof.

P.S. Can this statement be right for any devider, not $2^k$ but any positive number?

Comment: @lulu that only shows that the map $j \mapsto 5j + 1 \mod 2^k$ is a bijection of $\{0, \dots, 2^k -1\}$. The fact that it has order $2^k$ is at least somewhat nontrivial.

Comment: @sbares  You're right, I misread the question.

Comment: Upon doing a little digging, the proof is in Theorem 1 here: https://chagall.med.cornell.edu/BioinfoCourse/PDFs/Lecture4/random_number_generator.pdf
See also the wikipedia page on linear congruential generators.

Comment: If you haven't found a source  "with a proof of this statement," you should at least identify for your Readers what source(s) provide the statement beyond the Cython(?) code linked.  I'm sure you can quickly edit in some further context, so I'm skipping the Close Review vote for now.